# How to set different media-queries for laptop 1024px and ipad 1024px width?

Tags: html, css, ipad, responsive-design, media-queries

I want to set different media queries for 1024px width screens depending on whether it's a laptop screen or iPad screen.

For example if someone view my site in laptop(width : 1024px) they should see an image and if they view it from iPad(width : 1024px ) the image should be hidden(display:none).

Answer (score 5):

You probably mean iPad Pro whose width is `1024px`.

You can detect whether the device is an iPad or a laptop using media queries by checking for the device height: iPad Pro height is `1366px` which, I think, is higher than the height of any laptop, so the CSS would look like this:

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (min-height: 1320px) {
    /* iPad Pro */
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-height: 1310px) {
    /* Laptop */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the width of the screens are the same size, CSS can't distinguish them from each other I guess.

You can use JavaScript. The `platform` property, from the `navigator` object, returns a string with the platform the browser is used on. (i.e. MacIntel, Win32) (Usage: `platform.navigator`)

For disabling and enabling stylesheet this might work for you: http://www.codechewing.com/library/how-to-disable-or-enable-a-stylesheet-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

for ipad specific media queries use below code,

if u want to hide img in ipad at 1024px width i.e. landscape mode u can use class "hide-me-landscape"

if u want to hide img in ipad with landscape and portrait mode use class "hide-me"

if u want to hide img in portrait mode use class "hide-me-portrait"

see below code for ex

```
/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
    .hide-me{
        display: none;
    }
}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (orientation: portrait) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
    .hide-me-portrait{
        display: none;
    }

}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (orientation: landscape) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
    .hide-me-landscape{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

you can learn more about it [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

you can also use [modernizr](https://modernizr.com/) to detect whether user is using touch screen device or not and apply your css accordingly

hope it helps :)